# Storyboard vs. Media.Animations

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, performance, animation

suppose you want to animate something, Which one is better to use by performance?

using `Storyboards` in XAML ?

*OR*

classes like `DoubleAnimation` in `Media.Animation` in Code-Behind?

Comment: `Storyboard` is not an animation. It runs animation, like `DoubleAnimation`. It gives your animation timeline that you can pause, resume, seek or stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said previously, Storyboards are not Animation, thus you can't compare them.

I must suppose that your question is about creating a DoubleAnimation in code behind or in XAML like that:

```
<Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation />
</Storyboard>
```

Thus, your question is pretty similar to: is there a performance difference if I create my object in XAML or in C# code behind.

And my answer is...You should really don't care, at first. To quote a certain Kent Beck: Make it works, make it clean, make it fast. In WPF, to make it clean, you should implement MVVM to have a clear separation of concern. And an animation is clearly an UI concern, so it should be design in the view: your xaml file.

Now if I try to anwser your question anyway, there is almost no performance difference, because a DoubleAnimation object is created eventually in any case.

So do it in XAML, it will be better for the architecture of your software.

Let me conclude by this: if you really have performance constraints for your application, WPF is probably a poor choice anyway as it was not designed to be efficient. The real power of WPF is to allow this clear separation of concern.

Answer (score 0):

1st thing is `StoryBoard` is not an animation. If you follow below example:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
  <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
    AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
</Storyboard>
```

Here animation is created and applied it to the rectangle's Opacity property using `StoryBoard`

More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019%28VS.95%29.aspx)